# JQuery multiple windows opening becaudse of classes

Tags: jquery

Been trying to find a solution all day and its driving me nuts. I have a page being compiled via XSLT and when I click on the Twitter social link to share details about an article, its opening a new window for every instance of the class rather than just the one clicked.

Please can you take a look at the following page and click on one of the Twitter links:

http://search.stoneburndemo.com/search?q=a&btnG.x=-564&btnG.y=-178&filter=0&daterange_ddm=all&as_q=&site=default_collection&client=alhayat_production&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=alhayat_production&lr=lang_ar&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&proxyreload=1&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&exclude_apps=1&tlen=88

This is the code I am using:

```
<script>
$('.twitter_sl').find('a').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.twitter_sl').children('a').click(function(){

var twitterOrigURL = $(this).attr('title').replace(/\%20/g, '%2520'),
    twitterURL = twitterOrigURL,
    twitterText = $(this).attr('name');

window.open('http://www.twitter.com/share?text='+twitterText+'&amp;url='+twitterURL,'_blank', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=250,width=600');
});
</script>
```

The HTML markup is:

```
<td class="twitter_sl">
<a title="{$full_url}" name="{T}"><img src="http://daharchives.alhayat.com/images/t_logo.png" alt="Share on Twitter" height="25px" width="25px"/></a>
</td>
```

The issue is somewhat hidden in Chrome, as it seems to block all but one of the pop up windows. Firefox highlights the issue best, by not blocking any and opening 10 new windows.

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the class `.twitter_sl`

Comment: Thats been done above...

Comment: When I click a Twitter link, only one window opens..

Comment: Please check in Firefox. The thing is Chrome especially, will block all the pop ups except one to give which is why I thought I had solved it until the client got back to me...

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. May want to update the question, that's important info!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should keep presentational stuff in the CSS. Do a rule in your stylesheet for
   `.twitter_sl { cursor: pointer; }`
2. You can modify your click event to be more granular like this:

   ```
   $('.twitter_sl > a').on('click', function(){
       var that = $(this),
           twitterOrigURL = that.attr('title').replace(/\%20/g, '%2520'),
           twitterText = that.attr('name');

       window.open('http://www.twitter.com/share?text=' + twitterText + '&amp;url=' + twitterOrigURL, '_blank', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=250,width=600');
   });
   ```

Edit: Here's a fiddle, it works just fine in FF. http://jsfiddle.net/5nC4q/3/

Comment: Yeah I was going to be moving that to the CSS, was just trying to solve the JQuery issue first.

Thanks for the reply, however, that hasn't solved it...

Comment: The function I wrote only clicks one thing at a time, so I'd look in your HTML and JS for collisions and perhaps stacked elements.

Comment: Am I right in assuming the issue is that there are 10 instances of the .twitter_sl?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the XSLT but it still opens multiple windows.

However, your fiddle works perfectly...

Comment: It was a school boy error, the script was within an xsl-template which was creating/generating the script for every instance. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 0):

I guess by iterating over the links with .each() every single one has its "own click"

```
<script>
$('.twitter_sl').find('a').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.twitter_sl').children('a').each(function(){

$(this).click(function(){

var twitterOrigURL = $(this).attr('title').replace(/\%20/g, '%2520'),
twitterURL = twitterOrigURL,
twitterText = $(this).attr('name');

window.open('http://www.twitter.com/share?text='+twitterText+'&amp;url='+twitterURL,'_blank',      'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=250,width=600');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt help as it goes through all the classes found and opens a new window...